# "insert on duplicate update" still inserts duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql table with descriptionId as a primary key and it is auto incremented. it also has a "content" and a "price" columns and few more.

I also have a form consisting of multiple input boxes with the current database values of my price and content columns in my description table. after submitting the form i'd like to update the table with the new values and if any of the input boxes is deleted, the record must be deleted from the table.

I have also managed to define three arrays to hold the values of all my tables' columns. These Arrays are as followed: $descrId,$content,$price

when i submit my form, the php file loops through theses arrays and executes the following query:(I have validate these arrays so they work just fine)

```
INSERT INTO     
description(descriptionId,content,price,orderNo,salesPerson,dateTime,updated)
VALUES('{$descrId[$k]}','{$content[$k]}','{$price[$k]}','{$orderId}','{$sale}',NOW(),1 ) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE content=VALUES(content),price=VALUES(price),updated=1, dateTime=NOW()
```

However, this query keeps duplicating the values anytime i press submit.

I appreciate your time....

Comment: I don't see the KEY to check for duplicates or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have a unique key on those columns you do not want to have duplicates? Also you do not need to insert `descriptionId` when it is autoincrement.

Comment: The key is *descriptionId* ad is the only field that is being considered on the duplicate key section. Are you sure that the *descriptionId* is being duplicated, or is it the other data only?

Comment: "descriptionId as a primary key and it is auto incremented"... If your primary key is auto-incremented how would you expect it to be *duplicated*?!

Comment: all the other fields are duplicated but not the primary key, meaning i get the same values inserted into to my table. they are not duplicated in my table but i have repeated rows in my table(except of course the descriptionId)

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `description` (
  `descriptionId` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(9,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orderNo` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `salesPerson` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `dateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`descriptionId`),
  KEY `orderNo` (`orderNo`),
  KEY `salesPerson` (`salesPerson`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=780 ;

Answer (score 1):

As I read your question `ON DUPLICATE KEY` will never occur, because your *primary key*  is an auto incremented value, which will be +1 each time your insert something in the table, so it will never have a duplicated value - that's the idea more or less behind `AUTO INCREMENT`.

So the answer is to pick another column, i.e. `orderNo` or `dateTime`, make it `UNIQUE` and then try again with the query.

**Update**
Alternatively you can combine two or more columns and define them as a (unique) key.
If that's also not applicable in your case, then use some hashing function/algorithm when inserting the data and store that hash along the other values in the table.

Comment: thank u for ur fast response. none of the other columns can be unique in my table as they tend to have common values. is there anyway i can solve that problem?

Comment: even not `orderNo` ? Do you have different descriptions for one and the same òrderNo`? `dateTime`would be another candidate eventually

Comment: each orderNo has many descriptions so the orderNo cannot be unique. and as of dateTime since few descriptions are added to the database simultaneously, the dateTime cannot be unique either. is there any other alternatives?

Comment: You can have a combination of two or more columns as a (unique) key. Have a look at [MySQL's Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html) just after *Partitioning*

Comment: See also the **Update** to my answer